# Running php files for dev and test purposes

Tags: php, helper

When people are making changes to or adding new php files such as helpers what is the standard way of testing these. Should they be ran like a shell script first or through a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer using Ecomdev_PHPunit for this:

- https://github.com/EcomDev/EcomDev_PHPUnit (use the dev branch!)
- http://www.ecomdev.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/EcomDev_PHPUnit-0.2.0-Manual.pdf

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was curious to see how other people do it